# How to query for column sum only if other column are the same in sqlite3?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have this table "stocks" which records every transaction from every users:

```
user_id ticker  qty price_order time_order  price_now
18      AAPL    5   300         NULL        259.43
18      GOOG    10  200         NULL        1186.51
18      AAPL    -2  200         NULL        259.43
20      AAPL    10  200         NULL        259.43
20      AAPL    -5  200         NULL        259.43
```

And I'm querying, for example, user 18 with

`SELECT ticker, SUM(qty), price_order, time_order FROM stocks JOIN users ON user_id = id WHERE id = 18`
:

```
ticker  SUM(qty)    price_order time_order
AAPL    13          200         NULL
```

This is not what I intended. I need to sum only rows with the same ticker.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use group by

```
SELECT ticker, SUM(qty), price_order, time_order FROM stocks JOIN users ON user_id = id WHERE id = 18 GROUP BY ticker
```

Comment: You are right, I've tried GROUP BY before knowing I need the SUM(qty) and it returned only the two first rows of the table, so I gave up trying to use it! Thanks for you attention.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `GROUP BY ticker` at the end.  This will aggregate rows that have the same ticker.

```
SELECT ticker, SUM(qty), price_order, time_order
FROM stocks JOIN users ON user_id = id
WHERE id = 18 
GROUP BY ticker
```